# How to style a PDF header/footer in Pupeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to generate, server-side, a PDF file from HTML. What I'm struggling with though is getting the header to be styled.

Here is how I'm using Puppeteer:

```
async toPDF(html: string, path: string, options?: IToPDFOptions): Promise<[string, Buffer]> {
        const browser = await Puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            args: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            ],
        });

        const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
        const page = await context.newPage();

        await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

        await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

        const pdf = await page.pdf({
            path,
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {
                bottom: 70,
                left: 56,
                right: 56,
                top: 150,
            },
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            headerTemplate: options?.header?.content,
            footerTemplate: options?.footer?.content,
        });

        await browser.close();

        return [path, pdf];
    }
```

And the header itself (passed to `options.header.content`):

```html
<div style="
        margin: 40px 56px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
</div>
```

After reading that Puppeteer is weird with headers/footers (can't read a `<style>` tag), I inlined the styles but to no avail.